# How to set mime type of custom zip file?

Tags: android, file, mime-types, intentfilter

In my application I have create zip file in SD Card and rename it to custom extension like

> **customzipfile.abc**

I have already use below code in manifest file but it's not working for me. I have also refer related link but it's fail for me.

```
<intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <data android:scheme="file" />
      <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
      <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.abc" />   
      <data android:host="*" />
</intent-filter>
```

Whenever I trying to get mime type it return null

```
 String fileExtension= MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(selectedUri.toString());
 String mimeType= MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(fileExtension);
```

I have to also store this file on Google Drive. Whenever I'm trying to get file list from drive, I can't get this file using IntentSender.

```
IntentSender intentSender = Drive.DriveApi
                   .newOpenFileActivityBuilder()
                   .setMimeType(new String[] { "application/abc" })
                   .build(getGoogleApiClient());
```

How to set mime type?

Answer (score 0):

If you set a custom file extension that the MimeTypeMap does not know, it can not get you the mimeType for it. It is only a mapping between the file endings and mimeTypes.

If you know, the only files that end in .abc are your zip files, just construct the mimeType yourself, or call the `getMimeTypeFromExtension()` method directily with `"zip"`.

Comment: Well, same issue for Google drive as i mentioned in the answer. Google drive does not know the mimeType `"application/abc"` and your renamed .zip file does not even has this mimeType. Depending on the method that google drive uses to determine the mimeType, it will either be unknown (if only the file ending is checked) or, it will still be `application/zip` if the file metadata is checked.

Comment: try with .setMimeType(new String[] { "application/zip"})

Comment: i have try but it only showing me zip file not abc file.